# select count from table upon other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have two tables (main_table) and (sub_table) related by person_id ..now i want to select person_id from main table and count of records in sub_table that related to main_table where records in sub_table not equal 'eco' .. now the problem is when i make this .. the query get only person_id that not equal 'eco' ... but i want from query to select every person_id and select count 0 if person_id in sub_table equal 'eco'  :

```
    SELECT m.person_id, COUNT(*) AS eco FROM  (SELECT person_id FROM Main_table
                    WHERE     (person_id ='c')AS m INNER JOIN
                      (SELECT  person_id
                         FROM         sub_table
                         WHERE person_status != 'eco' 
                         GROUP BY person_id) AS eco ON eco.person_id = m.person_id GROUP BY m.person_id
```

Comment: Which DBMS r u using  ?

Comment: sql server express 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are `INNER` joining to your sub_table, so you are by definition limiting the results to only people with an entry in this table that does not equal `eco`.

I think you can do this by simply left joining to your sub table, with the person_status in the join criteria:

```
SELECT  m.Person_ID,
        COUNT(s.Person_ID) AS NonEcoCount
FROM    Main_Table m
        LEFT JOIN sub_table s
            ON s.Person_ID = m.Person_ID
            AND s.person_status != 'eco'
GROUP BY m.Person_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.person_id, 
       countNonEco = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sub_table s
                      WHERE m.person_id = s.person_id
                      AND (s.person_status IS NULL OR s.person_status <> 'eco'))
FROM Main_table m
```